# E2010 Incompatible types: 'LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW' and 'PQueryServiceConfigA' error in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I have following code in Delphi 7 in some function:

```
 var
    objServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfigA;
    ...
    ...
    objServiceConfig:= AllocMem(anySize);
    ...
    ...
    QueryServiceConfig(hSCService, objServiceConfig, anySize, anySize2)
    .....
    .....
```

I am getting error: `E2010 Incompatible types: 'LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW' and 'PQueryServiceConfigA'`

In Delphi 7 everything is working fine but migrating it to Delphi XE4, I am getting this error.

When I change the above declaration `objServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfigA;` to `objServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG;` it works. Is it right or what else I have to do?

Update:

In Delphi XE4 WinSvc, QueryServiceConfig is declared like following

```
function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;  

{$EXTERNALSYM QueryServiceConfigA}

function QueryServiceConfigA(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGA; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

{$EXTERNALSYM QueryServiceConfigW}

function QueryServiceConfigW(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

In Delphi7, WinSvc, QueryServiceConfig is declared like following

```
function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfig; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

{$EXTERNALSYM QueryServiceConfigA}

function QueryServiceConfigA(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfigA; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

{$EXTERNALSYM QueryServiceConfigW}

function QueryServiceConfigW(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfigW; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

It means 2nd parameter in case of Delphi 7 is of type `PQueryServiceConfig`/A/W while in Delphi XE4 is of type `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG`/A/W

Comment: I'm sorry to nag, but you have asked a series of questions on your D7 -> XE4 migration now. That's just fine. But it seems to me that you are not making much effort to *understand* what you are doing. I get the sense that you just want to do whatever it takes to make your code compile. That will almost certainly lead your into a world of pain. Compiling your code is not enough. It must be correct as well, in order to be able to run it. I do feel that you would benefit from some more understanding. If you can gain that, you'll likely get to the end of your task quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi XE4 supports Unicode, and Delphi 7 is an ANSI version. So `QueryServiceConfig` maps to `QueryServiceConfigW` on XE4, but `QueryServiceConfigA` on D7.

To fix the problem (but see below) you should replace `PQueryServiceConfigA` with `PQueryServiceConfig`. Now, `PQueryServiceConfig` will map to `PQueryServiceConfigW` in Unicode Delphi and `PQueryServiceConfigA` in ANSI Delphi. And that's precisely the behaviour that you need.

More importantly you should make sure that you have read and understood [Marco Cantù's whitepaper on the Unicode changes introduced in Delphi 2009](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980). If you don't do that, and it looks like you have not, then your migration will lead to pain and suffering.

---

Actually, it's more complex than that. The above would all be accurate, if the Delphi header translation was correct. But it's not. It's been done incorrectly.

The declaration of `QueryServiceConfig` is:

```
function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

But it should be:

```
function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfig; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Because of that you'll need to declare your variable to be of type `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` to work around the error.

Sorry for taking so long to get to the bottom of this.

---

It seems that there's even more to it than this. TOndrej correctly points out that the state of the [`TYPEDADDRESS`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_%28Delphi%29) compiler directive, `$T`, has an impact. The default setting of this is `OFF`. In which case passing a `PQueryServiceConfig` to `QueryServiceConfig` results in the compiler error:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW' and 'PQueryServiceConfigW'
```

If you switch the setting to `ON`, which I strongly recommend, then the compilation succeeds.

To understand why, we need to look at how these types and the function are declared. I've stripped out the ANSI declarations to keep the exposition simple:

```
type
  LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = ^QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG = LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = record
    ...
  end;
  QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  _QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  PQueryServiceConfigW = ^TQueryServiceConfigW;
  PQueryServiceConfig = PQueryServiceConfigW;
  TQueryServiceConfigW = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  TQueryServiceConfig = TQueryServiceConfigW;

function QueryServiceConfig(... lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG ...
```

Now, in the `T-` state, the documentation says:

> In the {$T-} state, distinct pointer types other than Pointer are incompatible (even if they are pointers to the same type).

This explains the compilation error. Because `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` is distinct from `PQueryServiceConfig`.

Now, the types could have been declared this way:

```
type
  QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = record
  end;
  QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  _QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  TQueryServiceConfigW = QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  TQueryServiceConfig = TQueryServiceConfigW;

  LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW = ^QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG = LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  PQueryServiceConfigW = LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW;
  PQueryServiceConfig = PQueryServiceConfigW;
```

And then you could pass any of the four pointer types to the function since they are actually all aliases of the same type.

Comment: Replacing PQueryServiceConfigA with PQueryServiceConfig, I get same error.

Comment: That sounds rather implausible. Do you want to understand what's going on? Or do you just want to make the program compile?

Comment: I have updated my question and included QueryServiceConfig declaration in both Delphi XE4 and Delphi 7

Comment: Ah, finally I see it. On top of the explicit use of `PQueryServiceConfigA` in the question, which is wrong, there's a confounding error caused by a bogus header translation. My latest update will see you home.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: In my opinion the error in the translation is not in the function but in the pointer to the record. `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` should be = `PQueryServiceConfig`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No I don't think so. Look at the pattern established in the Windows unit, say. For instance, look at `TWin32FindData`. There are countless other examples. The struct `QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` is translated in the standard way. It's the procedure declaration that differs.

Comment: @David - Then the pattern established is wrong. What would be the point in having a `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` if you can't pass it to `QueryServiceConfig`?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I see what you mean now. I agree. If there is one single pointer type declared, and every other pointer type is an alias to that, then it doesn't matter how you declare the function.

Comment: @David - Indeed. And what forces this is the weird behavior of $T (here anyway), which I haven't even noticed until this question. I have a vote on every post on this page.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It seems that `$T-` if doubly bogus! It gives away type safety when you use `@` and then screws you over when you try to assign pointers. And yet it is still the default. I'd just remove the `$T-` mode and force everyone to wake up!

Answer (score 5):

You should simply use

```
var
  objServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfig;
```

That's declared as `PQueryServiceConfigA` (ANSI version) in Delphi 7 and as `PQueryServiceConfigW` (Unicode version) in Delphi XE4.

**Edit:**

Unless you have "Typed @ operator" compiler option turned on (`{$T+}`), this produces a compiler error `E2010 Incompatible types: 'LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIGW' and 'PQueryServiceConfigW'` in Delphi XE4.
So either use that option or simply redeclare the function like this:

```
function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE; lpServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfig; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external advapi32 name {$IFDEF UNICODE}'QueryServiceConfigW'{$ELSE}'QueryServiceConfigA'{$ENDIF};
```

This way it should compile in both Delphi 7 and XE4.

Comment: Replacing PQueryServiceConfigA with PQueryServiceConfig, I get same error.

Comment: I have updated my question and included QueryServiceConfig declaration in both Delphi XE4 and Delphi 7

Comment: +1 for the $T+. I wonder what's the point in disabling compatibility of pointers to the same type ($T-).